# Защита curl запроса

Tags: php

Есть curl запрос который принимает данные и записывает в бд.
Вопрос: есть ли какая уязвимость здесь и если есть то как защититься?
Я про подделывания запроса, дабы отправить заведомо ложный ответ в бд и тд...

P.s  Меня интересует не инъекция бд (sql), а все уязвимости curl, дабы те данные которые я спарсил попали в бд.

Так же видел, что создают отдельные классы под curl с анонимными функциями и хотелось бы услышать на сколько это эффективно, если это вообще помогает

```
$url ='Здесь запрос';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($output,1);
($data["USD"]["last"]) // Эти данные отправляем в бд
```

Comment: Где у вас тут в коде запись данных в бд?

Comment: Ну, присобачьте какой-нибудь уник-токен, который будет рандомного генериться и шифроваться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам по себе cURL запрос просто получает нужные данные с указанного в параметрах хоста. Если речь про MITM-атаку, то можете сами попробовать провести ее на практике через Fiddler и посмотреть в каких случаях данные выдаются, а в каких нет. Если HTTP, то подделать его не составляет проблемы. Если HTTPS, то с этим сложнее, но тоже есть варианты. Степень защиты здесь настраивается на стороне сервера и клиент (а в данном случае cURL это и есть клиент), только выполняет Handshake.

Также в вашем коде нет самой записи данных в БД, поэтому не могу оценить безопасность кода (именно здесь обычно и происходит инъекция, если речь про поддельный хост). На этом этапе обязательно используйте фильтрацию спецсимволов или подготовленные выражения.

Comment: А есть примеры? Охотно посмотреть... Но меня интересует не инъекция бд (sql), а все уязвимости curl, дабы те данные которые я спарсил попали в бд

Comment: Видел что создают отдельные классы под curl с анонимными функциями и хотелось бы услышать на сколько это эффективно, если это вообще помогает